# How do I define the correct arc of a circle?

Tags: circles, polar-coordinates, tessellations

A start and end point as well as another point on the arc are given, which together define an arc of a circle. The points are given in polar coordinates. When defining such an arc, how do I ensure that the starting angle (angle of the starting point) is always smaller than the ending angle (angle of the end point). In the below image [image: following image] you can see the starting angle is 45 degree and the ending point is 135 degree. If the angle of the another point is between 45 and 135 I want get the purpule arc, else the blue arc, **but (for my tesselation pipline) I need to ensue that the starting angle i always lower than the ending angle.**

Comment: You can transform angles with this function $f(\theta,\theta_0)=(((\theta-\theta_0)\mod {2\pi})+3\pi)\mod {2\pi})-\pi$ relatively to a starting point at $\theta_0$. This allows to sort the points in the correct order. (see an example here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2449617/399263)

Comment: Your very figure shows that this is impossible unless you supply an extra bit of information, such as the rotational direction.

Comment: If it is the other point that determines which of the two arcs you want, then surely you are free to swap the start and end values.